# Generate dependencies list from list of jar files

Tags: gradle

We are planning to move our current project to Gradle. Currently we have all the library jar files stored inside the project.
To list this jar files in Gradle project, is there any way to get the list of existing library jar files in Gradle project, so that we don't have to hand code it.

Comment: "Currently we have all the library jar files stored inside the project": what do you mean by that? Could you post an example?

Comment: Currently we have our jar files checked-in to source control, once we move to Gradle all these will come from repository.  As part of this migration, i am wondering is there any automated script to generate this list of dependencies from the existing lib files.

Comment: This is something that should never be done in the Maven world. Maven and Gradle are very much alike and they have the same concepts. You could also move first to properly using Maven! :)

Comment: I can only assume you have a huge pile of libraries. You will just have to do the chore: There is no "standard naming convention" or "metadata file" inside of JAR files identifying their maven central name. Also, if you need a search, try [bintray's jCenter](https://bintray.com/), a superset of Maven Central - it comes with a maven package search